# I want to get sliding functionality in my app which is a fragment

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, slide

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/services">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBalance"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="@string/btnBalance" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMeeting"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="@string/btnNextMeetingDateTime" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/first"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBalanceTransfer"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="@string/btnBalanceTransfer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMobileTopUp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="@string/btnMobileTopUp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/second"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStatement"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="@string/btnStatement" />
        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout I want to replace this layout when button is click and replace with another fragment layout with sliding effect to right .. I could get the functionality but only the top linear layout is replaced while I want to replace whole layout. The code I wrote in onClick even is this

```
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager()
             .beginTransaction();
             fragTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,
             R.anim.slide_right);
             Meeting fragMeeting = new Meeting();
             fragTransaction.replace(R.id.first, fragMeeting);
             fragTransaction.addToBackStack("test");
             fragTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Can you add more code? You must have 1 Activity, 2 Fragments and 3 xml layouts..?

Comment: Can u describe the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

take one `RelativeLayout` inside your parent `RelativeLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    //your LinearLayout code

</RelativeLayout>
```

and give its id in `fragTransaction.replace`

```
fragTransaction.replace(R.id.main, fragMeeting);
```

Comment: it doesn't work ..the new fragment overlaps the old one

Answer (score 0):

you replaced **R.id.first** with your fragment
where as to replace whole view, you have to write
**android.R.id.content**

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left,R.anim.slide_right);
Fragment fragMeeting = new Meeting();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragMeeting);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

if my answer help, kindly make it +1

Comment: it over laps the current layout with old one

Comment: you should change to addToBackStack(null),
Please check my updated answer

Comment: please share screenshot, how is it looking, then I can help!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is the screen shot. The Back button and the text view is the fragment I want to replace current fragment with

Answer (score 0):

I managed to overcome the problem of overlapping the fragment but changing the background color to white but new problem came up that is the fragment shown after clicking the button shows in every tab... any fixes or ideas I have missed to understand that I can read?